# Intellij Remote Wildfly

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-server, wildfly-8

Please, please help me!!!!

When I try to launch my wildfly through a web browser, it's completely OK.
I do this with the address below: 192.168.2.191:8080

But when I try to use it through my intellij, I can't make it work.
This is my configuration:

Application Server: Jboss 8.2.0 Final

Management Port: 8080

Username : administrator

Password : *****

Operating mode : stand alone

Host:192.168.2.111

Port:8080

I have also tried the ports 9990 and 9999 for the port management part.

The error I get is:

Error running Wildfly
           Unable to connect to the 192.168.2.191:8080, reason:
           com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to http-remoting://192.168.2.191:8080. The connection failed

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt you've set wildfly to run on port `8080` for management.  If you take a look at your `standalone.xml` you should see a line like this:

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
```

The default shown here is `9990`  please check for that line and try that port # out.  `8080` is the HTTP listener for the applications.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply.
My problem was that, when I changed the management port, I changed the port with it too. So it couldn't find it anymore.